# retina.js v2.0 not working for images

Tags: retina.js

I trying to use retina.js v2.0 to swap images, but it's not working, I don't know why. I also check it in developer tools, but there's not any error. Can u help me, what could be the problem?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/logo.png" data-rjs="2" alt="Logo">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="retina.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you figured this out? I am having the same issue.  I found a resolution, by calling retinajs() directly after the script loads. But, reading the [How It Works](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) documentation does not say you need to do this.

Here is what I did:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="/images/nav_logo.png" data-rjs="2">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/retina/retina.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        retinajs();
    </script>
</body>
```

**Yes, this works but my question is whether it is "right"?**